# Networking and Traffic routing question

Tags: networking, routing

Hello I had a few of questions related to networking, let me list them in a logical order:

1) Can multiple interfaces be bridged together so that it results in increased bandwidth?

2) Can wired and wireless interfaces be bridged together?

3) If you have multiple interfaces (both wired and wireless), which one would have higher precedence and where would all the traffic be routed to?

For the above questions, I'm referring to a single Linux based system.

Please try to explain in details if possible, I didn't find much resources else where to help me on this topic. Also try to point towards reference material(s) where applicable.

Thanks.

Comment: [Yes](https://www.thirdlight.com/docs/display/integration/Network+interface+bonding).  There are [multiple ways to bond WANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation): failover, [policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) [routing](http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/ONLINE/TOC.html), [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Load_Balancing)...  Here are [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding). With
 [Nethserver](https://www.nethserver.org/) it's out of the box. [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) has a multiwan package.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty original question.  I can only answer part 3).

Your routing table determines which interface is used.

The shell command:

`route`

dumps your current routing table. It shows which network interfaces are being used for each destination network. The output includes a `metric` for each rule for determining 'precedence' by the routing code in the network stack (part of the Linux kernel).  The `default` route is the catch-all destination for anything that didn't match other routing rules.

You may also use `ifconfig -a` to see which interfaces are available on your system.

The routing table can be also be modified (as root) with the `route` command by passing the `add` or `del` to add or delete routes (`man route` for full details) but unless you really know what you're doing, you should leave this job to the network manager.